# UPSERT a Pandas DataFrame into Snowflake DB

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to upsert a pandas dataframe into a snowflake database. Is there any documentation that can help me.

I am working with a large streaming data with around 50 columns. Creating a temporary table proves less efficient as I have to write a clause to update or insert around 50 column values.

Any advice is helpful. THANK YOU.

Comment: Does sometimes like [this](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-pandas.html#writing-data-from-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-snowflake-database) helps or you need to use SQLAlchemy?

Comment: This helps with basic insert operation. I don't think it helps with insert/update. The same goes for sqlalchemy, which atleast has snowflake dialect for MergeInto, but trying to typescript 50 columns is not the most efficient programming strategy.